# Vite and React: stop using "react-refresh"

Tags: reactjs, npm, vite

Whenever I run npm start in my project I get the following message:

```
[@vitejs/plugin-react] You should stop using "react-refresh" since this plugin conflicts with it.
```

Vite seems to work fine regardless, but I was wondering if / how I should disable "react refresh"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Check your `vite.config.js` file. Since you are using `@vitejs/plugin-react`, you should see something like this (plus any other configuration):

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react';

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    react({
      babel: {
        plugins: ['babel-plugin-macros', ... (plugins here)],
      },
    }),
  ],
});
```

In the plugin array, if you have `reactRefresh()`, this means you are using `@vitejs/plugin-react-refresh` as well as `@vitejs/plugin-react`. This is unnecessary since plugin-react has hot refresh built-in and customisable. It probably won't break your code as far as I know but you can safely delete it.

Comment: Removing react-refresh from the list of plugins fixed it for me. Thanks!